# How does bigquery behaves while processing large file set

Tags: google-bigquery

Does big query support ACID properties?
After processing large number of files and the last one fails,would that rollback the entire job load?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, BigQuery jobs have ACID properties. That is, they are

- Atomic: Either they commit entirely or not at all.
- Consistent: Changes should be available everywhere, and once a job has completed successfully, that data should be seen on every subsequent job.
- Isolated: Concurrent jobs operate independently.
- Durable: Once a job has finished, the data should be written durably (currently, that means that it is written to at least 3 replicas.)

When jobs start they are checked for validity (for example, are you appending data with the right schema) but no changes are made until the job is ready to commit. At that point the changes are applied atomically (and validated again).

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid, but this is not true.
BigQuery jobs support only the ATOMIC property.
This means that there aren't half-way state in jobs and if job fails all of it operations fails.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs