# Result of Bigquery job running on a table in which data is loaded via streamingAPI

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BQ wildcard query that merges a couple of tables with the same schema (company_*) into a new, single table (all_companies). (all_companies will be exported later into Google Cloud Storage)

I'm running this query using the [BQ CLI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/bq-command-line-tool%20BQ%20CLI) with all_companies as the destination table and this generates a BQ Job (runtime: 20mins+).

The company_* tables are populated constantly using the [streamingAPI](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery).

I've read [about BigQuery jobs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24941771/how-does-bigquery-behaves-while-processing-large-file-set), but I can't find any information about streaming behavior.

If I start the BQ CLI query at T0, the streamingAPI adds data to company_* tables at T0+1min and the BQ CLI query finishes at T0+20min, will the data added at T0+1min be present in my destination table or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described [here](https://cloud.google.com/blog/big-data/2017/06/life-of-a-bigquery-streaming-insert) the query engine will look at both the Columnar Storage and the streaming buffer, so potentially the query should see the streamed data.

It depends what you mean by a runtime of 20 minutes+. If the query is run 20 minutes after you create the job then all data in the streaming buffer by T0+20min will be included. 
If on the other hand the job starts immediately and takes 20 minutes to complete, you will only see data that is in the streaming buffer at the moment the table is queried.

Comment: I'm in the latter case: the job just runs the query and takes 20 minutes to complete. So, if I understand everything right: using the wildcard query company_\*, the data that will be in the output of the query is the columnar data of all company_* tables + their streaming buffer data at the moment that the query has started execution.

Comment: Yes, that's the way I understand it. 20 minutes to run the query sounds like it might get expensive :)